# How Does WordPress divide One Picture into Different Sizes?

Tags: php, wordpress

How Does WordPress divide One Picture into Different Sizes? I want to convert all pictures into one specific size after upload in core PHP.. Any Idea??

Comment: Visit this link : http://www.9lessons.info/2011/06/image-upload-and-cropping-with-php-and.html

Comment: Thanks..@Prakash Rao